# Pygame music will not play inside of my game function

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make some calming background music to play during the battle phase of my game, my game runs inside of a function and whenever I call on the function to play music it will just stay silent until I exit the game() function, then the music will suddenly kick in, I will appreciate any insight into what could be causing this.

```
def game():
        running = True
        while running:
                screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
                sewer = pygame.image.load('assets\\backgrounds\\sewer.png')
                screen.blit(sewer,(0,0))
                mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                turn = 0
                mob()
                monster_health()
                stopmusic()
                pmusic("assets\\music\\battlemusic.mp3")



def stopmusic():
    pygame.mixer.music.stop()

def pmusic(file):
    pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

Comment: It seems you start and stop the music every frame. Call pmusic before the while loop and remove stopmusic and pmusic from inside the while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `pmusic()` right after calling `stopmusic()`.
So everytime you enter your game loop, the music is turning off and starting again right away. When you end the game, you exit the while loop after having turned on the music, which is why you're hearing it afterwards.
You should launch your music before entering the game loop, and stop it when exiting :

```
def game():
    running = True
    pmusic("assets\\music\\battlemusic.mp3")
    while running:
        ...
    stopmusic()
```